# How do I get my ASUS X401A laptop's SD/MMC card reader to recognize I have an SD card inserted?

Tags: windows-10, sd-card, asus-laptop

I bought two external SD card readers for my laptop and just today realized I have a 2-in-1 card reader (SD/MMC) on my laptop! But when I tried putting a 16 GB SD card into the slot and pushing it in, it wouldn't really go in. The following picture shows the direction in which I inserted the card.

[image: DirectionSdCardInserted]

What I mean by this is that I put it into the opening that is labeled SD and about maybe half an inch of the card is sticking out of the slot. 
I then tried pushing the card inside (where there's not any part of the card sticking out of the slot) and there's a sort of soft "click" noise that sounds like the card has been clicked into place. But when I move my finger off of the SD card it doesn't stay inside of the slot, it goes back to having half an inch sticking out. Following is the photo of what it continuously goes back to with the bit sticking out of reader slot.

[image: SDCardInReaderSlot]

What am I doing wrong? Please help me; I have to upload photos to my computer to send to one of the student newspaper journalist at my college!

Comment: "It wouldn't really go in" is rather vague. Can you [edit] your question to be more specific about what exactly happens when you push the card into the slot?

Comment: ok i'll try haha

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how old the laptop is, the built-in card reader may have become fouled from cupric corrosion on the connectors, or it may be a corrupted driver in the OS. I would run updates first to make sure that the driver is installed, then make sure it is the most current one (I like to use SlimDrivers for this), and then try the card again. If your computer has a plastic place-holder that goes in the slot, it will show you the best way to insert the card by example.

If it still acts up take the machine apart to get to the motherboard and look at the slot itself. If it has corrosion, try to clean it as much as possible with 99% Isopropyl Alcohol. If it's still not working after that, then you will have to use the external readers because it is most likely that there is a blown component on that circuit.

I noticed that my own built-in was really touchy when it comes to reading cards so I cleaned the slot in the same fashion described and it works now without having to finagle with it.

Comment: I don't know how to take apart a computer... i'd be too scared to break it and i can't afford a new one right now... And I want to be using my external card readers but I left them in my dorm accidentally when I went home for spring break. Sadly I need to upload them to the school newspaper reporter today because they're desperately wanting them...

Comment: I can see the dilemma. If they're standard sized SD cards, then you would have to find another computer to do the transfer if it is corrosion on the pins. If you use Micro SD cards, then why not use your phone to transfer them over?

You might be able to set up a sort of cleaning jig to get to the pins if you use a thin enough cloth cut to the width of the slot lightly coated with Isopropyl. Wrap it around a card and the friction should be enough to clean the pins. Let it dry out before use, blowing lightly into the slot after cleaning should work because the evaporation point is much lower.

Comment: inside the computer?? cause the SD card I just bought yesterday at Walgreen's since my first one somehow got screwed up and was having problems inside my camera...